# Make an image accessible via HTTP

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to make a file, for example, `c:\users\user\documents\screenshot.png` to be accessible from the network and have its own url: `content.efolio.com/p/123/screenshot.png`.

At the moment I store the file path in the database table. When a request comes, file gets converted to Base64 string and sent inside JSON.

```cs
public class Project 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public string PhotoEncoded { get; set; }

  public string Description { get; set; } 

  public void AddPhoto(byte[] content, string fileFormat) 
  {
    PhotoEncoded = string.Format("data:image/{0};base64,{1}", 
      fileFormat.Substring(1,fileFormat.Length-1), 
      Convert.ToBase64String(content)
    );
  }
}
```

But i want to send only url. The problem is that I don't know how to make a file available via url. How do I do that in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out! You just have to make a `ContentController` which will serve individual files and use `File()` method in `ControllerBase`:

```cs
[ApiController] 
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ContentController : ControllerBase
{
   [HttpGet("project/{id}/{fileName}")] 
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetProjectThumbnail(int id, string fileName)
   {
       try
       {
           return File(await _projects.GetThumbnailAsync(id, fileName), "image/jpeg");
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new ErrorResponse(ex));
       }
   }
   //...
}
```

After that, I can access a thumbnail via url: `https://efolio.com/content/project/1003/1.jpg`

Comment: I think this is the way to go (haven't tested it though). If you need several images/files, u can make petitions to the same endpoint in parallel, which should be more time efficient than having one endpoint to retrieve many images/files at once.